# Debian hdmi not working after installing nvidia driver

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm using 2 monitors on my debian 11 laptop and using and HDMI cable to connect to a secondary monitor. While developing a code I set up opencl drivers thus downloaded nvidia drivers.

The process of setting the drivers was a bit complicated so I downloaded a lot of nvidia related stuff but in the end I managed to make it work and running.

However in doing so my secondary monitor stopped working. When I run `xrandr --output HDMI1 --output HDMI2` I get

```bash
warning: output HDMI1 not found; ignoring
warning: output HDMI2 not found; ignoring
```

The secondary monitor stays open however it's just a black screen. When I unplug or plug the HDMI cable it briefly says 'NO HDMI CONENCTED' over a blue screen (My laptop and screen are both asus).

I have 2 GPU's one intel gpu controller and an nvidia gpu. Here is the `` result:

```bash
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. N56VZ
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
        Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

```bash
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (
rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. N56VZ
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f7000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

I can't remember the command I ran to setup the opencl/nvidia driver's but here are some of them:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-opencl-icd`

`sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-libopencl1`

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`

How can I fix this and make my secondary screen work again?